# How to insert data in SQL database without duplicates

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a SQL Server database with:

| database 1 | database 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| B | B |
| C | C |

This will be inserted in a new db (database 2 here) for backup reasons.
After the insert my database1 will collect new data but also keeps the old data for some days. So the next hour the program runs another insert. I don't want to have ABC stored again in database 2. This time D E needs to be added:

| database 1 | database 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| B | B |
| C | C |
| D | D |
| E | E |

This is an example how it not should be:

| database 1 | database 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| B | B |
| C | C |
| D | A |
| E | B |
|  | C |
|  | D |
|  | E |

What is the best way to do this and also the fastest way ? I'm using SQL database with ADO.NET in C# at the moment.

Using the SQL creator in visual Studio which is connected to a SQL Server Express:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MBR] 
(
    [Id]          INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp]   DATETIME     NOT NULL,
    [TAG]         VARCHAR(80)  NOT NULL,
    [Value]       VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL,
    [Description] VARCHAR(128) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Which database engine are you using, Sql Server? All relational databases have column constrains, "unique" is one of them. Can you provide your table definition?

Comment: As @gunr2171 said.  Use a UNIQUE constraint.  The only way to ensure the data follows some format in the database is to make the constraint on the database level.

Comment: Are you trying to push data to two different copies of the same database each time you manipulate data, one "live" and one "backup"?

Comment: The "Sql creator in visual studio" connects to _something_, whether it be an installed Sql Server instance, or Sql Express. What's the connection string you're using in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you have database 1 (the used database for your API or something) and database 2 (backup database). And when you have back upped a record you do not want to backup it again.

How do you do the clean up and copying? If this is a program you can think about adding an extra field in database 1 named something like "IsBackedUp". In this you can store a boolean value if you have already made a backup of this record and just toggle it to the correct status.

If you let the database do the backups through a query. Then you could write a subquery in your where statement that checks if the record does not already exist.

Depending on the size of the project I would recommend making a clean up program for cleaning up the data and backups. This is in my opinion a good feature to have for software that will work with larger amounts of data and gives you more control on what to backup and what not. Same for cleaning.